# Converting JavaScript variable to C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a variable in JavaScript and I want to use it as an index reference in my C# code. How do I convert the JavaScript variable into something C# can use? So far this is what I have..

```
@{
var selectedStockLocation = @Html.Raw(Json.Decode(document.getElementById("cbLocation " + id).value));

var currentLocation = Model.StockLocationBinData[selectedStockLocation];
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516293/how-to-access-a-javascript-variable-from-code-behind-in-asp-net/9516345#9516345

Comment: Where is the javascript? Where is the javascript variable?

Comment: could you post some more code to see how you want to communicate between View and your controller. @AndreLoker: I think that post is about how to handle it in webforms.

Comment: @PraveenLearnsEveryday right, but the issue is the same - he needs to post the data to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to post the value back with either a full POST or an AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing server and client code there.

You need to use (one of many) methods to post client data back to the controller.

Use jquery to write to a hidden variable in the form is one route, see this answer: 
[Passing a jQuery value to MVC 3 Razor view html helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035450/passing-a-jquery-value-to-mvc-3-razor-view-html-helper)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript runs well after the server-side code has rendered and completed; you cannot use it while rendering the view..  You can, however, store the value in a hidden field, put this hidden field in a form, and process it during a post operation.  Or, send it to the server via an AJAX callback.